# Download a PDF file using Watin when browser has Adobe PDF Add-in

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

Am trying to download a PDF file using Watin. Every time I try to download a PDF file the Adobe PDF Addin opens it in the browser. It never prompts to download the file. Does anyone have any examples of how to download a PDF file as I can't seem to figure this out. I am using IE11 and Watin 2.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just wrote an extension like this (automation is at best iffy) - sorry for vba.net:

```
 <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()> _
    Public Sub DownloadFile(browser As IE, fileUrl As String, savePath As String)

        Using wc As New WebClient
            Dim cookies As String = browser.Eval("document.cookie")
            If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(cookies) Then
                wc.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, cookies)
            End If

            wc.DownloadFile(fileUrl, savePath)
        End Using
    End Sub
```